# Promise is still been returned after await when converting image to base64 string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have the method below that converts an image to base64 string

```
  const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
```

Then I decide to use this function like below:

```
    let base_strings = files.map(async file => {
      let image = await toBase64(file);
      console.dir(image); //this console base string
      return image;
    });
```

but when I try to access my base_string array, I still get a promise like below:

[image]

I am not exactly sure of what I am doing wrong, I need to be able to get my base64 string in the array.

Comment: `async` in front of a function is syntactic sugar for "wrap the function result into a promise and return that". So you need to `await` all members of your array. (I'm not good enough at react to give a full answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Promise.all()` like this:

```
let base_strings = files.map(file => {
  return toBase64(file);
});

const myImages = await Promise.all(base_strings);
```

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting my answer by clicking the tick icon on the left under the arrow icon. @AbelAgoi

Answer (score 0):

map function return an Array you need to use Promise.all like that

```
await Promise.all(files.map())
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works too but I am going with @user9408899 answer. You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

`async await` dont work with `forEach` or `map` :

```
let base_strings = files.map(async file => {
    let image = await toBase64(file);
    console.dir(image); //this console base string
    return image;
});
```

You can do that with `simple for loop`, but that should be within `async` function like this :

```
const getFiles = async (files) => {
    const base_strings = [];
    for(let i=0;i<files.length; i++) {
        let image = await toBase64(file);
        console.dir(image); //this console base string
        base_strings.push(image);
    }
    return base_strings;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, just knowing this today. Great!

Comment: @AbelAgoi, if you need synchronous behavior, this is how you should do, `promise.all` make all requests together and not one by one

Comment: @AbelAgoi, if this is helpful to you, please also do upvote